# Не работает display: flex

Tags: flexbox, display

```
.top__inner {
display: flex;
}

Не работает данная команда для 

<section class="top"
<div class="container"
<div class="top__inner">

Помогите разобраться пожалуйста
```

Comment: а как именно Вы поняли, что не работает? сделайте воспроизводимый пример

Comment: Если вкратце, я только начинаю изучать верстку и данный код просто повторяю за автором видео, чтоб разобраться в процессах. Автор создал контейнер для отдельного блока на сайте, но забыл указать для отбельных блоков, как я понял, родителя — "top__inner", указав его, он использовал команду display: flex и у него все сработало, я же, повторив все в точности за ним, не получал похожего результата.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Arayl/pen/OJRpjLR вот сам код